# Extending a projection matrix

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to place a 3D heart inside of person using augmented reality. I have a projection matrix derived from an iPhone's camera intrinsics. Displaying objects relative to a framemarker works perfectly using the Vuforia SDKs generated projection matrix and pose. However, I would like to place an object in the scene behind the framemarker. To maintain the illusion any object behind the marker really needs to have the camera image in front of the object. Here is a drawing for the purposes of explanation.

[image: Problem illustration - heart should be drawn behind image]

Since the projection matrix will be the space in front of the image plane rather than the far plane, it seems to me I need to either extend the projection matrix or place the whole world inside another projection. Simply transposing the heart behind the marker doesn't work for the obvious reason you can never actually put anything behind the image plane. So the question I'm asking is, is this possible via some sort of projection matrix extension, or is there something else that would work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly a programming answer, but I will try to help.
I don't program for iOS XCode, rather I use Vuforia through Unity, and I just hope this gives you an idea on how to approach this apart from your method.

Unity has something called `DepthMask` this basically allows an Object to appear behind the ImageTarget. But since your application requires you to see through the ImageTarget you could try within `OnTrackingFound()` and change ImageTarget's

- `tranform.renderer.material.maintexture` to an transparent material
- `shader` and implement an `opacity` decrease

I'm aware this isn't as helpful as you'd expect, but I hope you do find an answer.

Good luck.

Comment: Funny thing about programming, it sometimes feels a lot like math. I'll look into this DepthMask. I should add I'm not using Vuforia to do the rendering, I'm using OpenGL ES as generated by VES/VTK.

Comment: I apologize, I meant it's not strictly a programming answer. Unity usually does the rendering and everything, so I don't know much about that.

Comment: I really want to try Unity, it has to be better than this mess. :)

Comment: It is, but you start to feel less of a Developer and more of a Designer when you do :P